# Deleting user from database of a WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf, oop

I was tasked to create a fitness application as an assignment at my school but in my main page I created an object of settings class and passed a value of a text box.

```
WPF_login.Pages.Settings s = new WPF_login.Pages.Settings(txtUsername.Text);
```

but inside settings page I cannot seem to delete the user when delete button clicked

```
namespace WPF_login.Pages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Settings.xaml
    /// </summary>
    class Person
    {
        public string name;
        public string getName(string namel)
        {
            return name;    
        }
    }
    public partial class Settings : Page
    {
        public string name;
        private SqlConnection connection;
    
        public Settings(string loggedUser)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Save the value of loggedUser in the name variable
            name = loggedUser;

            Person p = new Person();

            p.getName(loggedUser);

            string connectionString = "Data Source=DILEEKALAPTOP;Initial Catalog = FitnessGuidDB; Integrated Security = True;";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            bool loggedUserExists = CheckLoggedUserExists(loggedUser);

            if (!loggedUserExists)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Success: {p.name} exists", "Infromation", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
        }
        private bool CheckLoggedUserExists(string luser)
        {
            bool userExists = false;

            try
            {
                // Open the connection to the database
                connection.Open();

                // Create a new SqlCommand object to execute the SELECT statement
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM UserRegister WHERE U_name = '{name}'", connection);

                // Execute the query and get the results
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                // Check if there are any rows in the result set
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    userExists = true;
                }

                // Close the reader
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle any errors that occur
                MessageBox.Show($"Error: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close the connection to the database
                connection.Close();
            }

            return userExists;
        }



        public Settings()
        {
            
        }

        
        private void mobilechangebtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        
        }


        private void lbl_welcome_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void lbl_welcome_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           

        }

        private void Border_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            lbl_welcome.Content = name;
        }

        private void mobilechangebtn_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          
        }

        private void deleteuserbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Settings settings = new Settings();
           string loggedUser = settings.name;
           // MessageBox.Show($"Success: {loggedUser} exists", "Infromation", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            string LoggedUser = "dummy";
            string connectionString = "Data Source=DILEEKALAPTOP;Initial Catalog = FitnessGuidDB; Integrated Security = True;";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            try
            {
                // Open the connection to the database
                connection.Open();

                // Create a new SqlCommand object to execute the DELETE statement
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($"DELETE FROM UserRegister WHERE U_name = '{LoggedUser}'", connection);

                // Execute the query
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Set LoggedUser to null or an empty string to delete it
                LoggedUser = null; // or LoggedUser = "";

                // Show a success message to the user
                MessageBox.Show($"Successfully deleted user: {LoggedUser}", "Success", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                WPF_login.CreateUser c = new WPF_login.CreateUser();
                c.Show();
                //this.Hide();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle any errors that occur
                MessageBox.Show($"Error: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close the connection to the database
                connection.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong

I tried creating custom class called Person and setting it's name to loggedUser
I tried properties

Comment: What happens when you step through your code? You should be using parameters not string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Settings object using the empty constructor, it does not look like it is ever initialized.

Instead of:

```
       Settings settings = new Settings();
       string loggedUser = settings.name;
```

You could try:

```
       string loggedUser = name;
```